# Alt + Shift + E shortcut in pycharm, how to execute two connected lines of code with one key stroke

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

Let's say that I have the following simple code in pycharm editor.

```
dataframe = [1 , 12, 2,1 ,21,3 ,21,312,1 ,1,1 , 12, 2,1 ,21,3 ,
21,312,1 ,1, 2121]
```

in order to execute them, I have to select both lines (highlight them) and then press the keys <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

I am wondering if there is any other way, or settings to execute both lines without selecting them, but just press the key combination when the cursor is in one of the two lines, as it happens in R

Comment: have you checked the documentation for the `shift + alt + E` command? (I was looking for it myself for can't find it)

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the shortcut for 'Execute selection in console' via 'File --> Settings --> Keymap --> Other --> Execute selection in console' (Pycharm 3.6.x)and change the shortcut or you can just search the existing shortcut in the search box and change it. I also got used to the shortcut offered by Rstudio, so I changed it to 'F9' which might cause some conflicts but worked well in terms of efficiency.

Comment: What I want is not a shortcut, but when I have the cursor on the first line and run the line then pycharm understands that the command spans two lines and runs both of them. Apparently, this is not built in pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

With PyCharm Community 2020.1, navigate to Settings/Keymaps there is a magnifier icon "Find Action by Shortcut"; hit `shif + alt + E` and you'll see  under the folder <Plug-ins/Python Community Edition/> the action called "Execute Selection in Python Console"; change it to `ctrl + enter` and that'll do.